# Semi-reverting to master and checking changes

Tags: git, atlassian-sourcetree

Is there a good way to easily check how my current project differs from the master branch?  I'd like to somehow pull the master and 'resolve conflicts' again to double check the changes I've made.

I'm working on a side-project off a master - my project never gets merged to master but master gets developed on it's own.  I have an awkward bug now and I'd like to go through all the changes I've made to see where it is.  I have no idea if it's something I've done or some kind of core change made on master.  I don't want to undo all of my changes though, so I'm hoping there's a way to find this similar to how I describe above.

Edit:  I should probably note that 99% of the stuff I've done are in separate files that won't merge conflict - so it's not as simple as just going through the version changes I've made.  I need to find that 1% of code that ties my code into the main project itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest using the `bisect` command here, for convenience.

For sure, you *could* checkout, one by one, your commits, going backwards from `HEAD` until you find the breaking point, but `bisect` ,is intended to ease this very process. Hundreds of commits can be broken down to a few steps rather quickly this way.

Basically, it uses the principle of search by dichotomy, checking out a commit in-between two points in time (in your case, between now and the point where you branched off master), letting you run whatever tests you need, then awaiting for you to choose either to deem the commit "bad" (if your bug is present at this point of the timeline), or "good" (if the bug is not *yet* showing). Then it repeats the process, iteratively, until you've located the commit which brought trouble.

```
# to start the search
git bisect start

# to tag the present commit as "good"
git bisect good
# to tag the present commit as "bad"
git bisect bad

# to exit bisect mode and return to just before "bisect start"
git bisect reset
```

(*tag* used here in a colloquial sense, no real git tag involved of course, neither lightweight nor annotated)

Take a look at the [doc](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-bisect) (some other sub commands of `bisect` are handy, like `bisect log`), take a deep breath, grab your headlamp, and go for it.

Comment: I ran the bisect command but it doesn't seem to have done anything.  I may be missing the point.  I'm not sure what to type at the 2nd prompt.  Do I tag the current commit as 'bad' and work backwards?

Also - I didn't branch off from master a single time.  I branched off from master and pulled the latest updates from master.  Master is updated by a community team that are not involved with my personal copy and changes.  So I have pulled from master multiple times in between my commits and I think the error is somewhere in there as they may have changed the way something works.

Comment: You linked the docs - I should have looked there.  It explains the command better thanks I will try this.  Was hoping there'd be something more UI friendly in sourcetree but I'm not completely allergic to console stuff.

Comment: Thank you!  I found the error.  I'm a bit of a novice with git but there was one pull where there was some weird formatting stuff that I commented out because it was throwing errors.  I think it was actually a merge conflict and I was supposed to choose one or the other option - so commenting out the weird lines wound up duplicating code, which resulted in the behaviour I was seeing.  That was the point where the error occured.  For some reason neither sorcetree nor intellij flagged it as a merge conflict so I had no idea what I was supposed to do.